# AWS SDK Get All Files Between Date

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is there a way to get all files from an AWS Bucket that were uploaded between two dates? Right now I have the code below which is using the S3DirectoryInfo which returns information on ALL files in the corresponding bucket. Is there a way to get file info within a date range instead of grabbing information on all files in the bucket?

```
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretAccessKey, AWSRegion);
        S3DirectoryInfo dir = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, AWSBucketName);
        List<IS3FileSystemInfo> files = dir.GetFileSystemInfos().ToList();
```